# Using "Order by" twice in a single Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 2 columns.
`Date_Réserv`e(type of Date), `Heure_Réserve`(type of Time)

What I want to do is select the result ordered by the `Date_Réserve` and then thie result I get is ordered by `Heure_Réserve`.

this is the query I tried :

```
select * from (select Date_Réserve,Heure_Réserve from réserve order by Date_Réserve)t order by Heure_Réserve
```

But It gives me this error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, and subqueries, unless TOP is also specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List needed columns separated by comma:

```
select Date_Réserve, Heure_Réserve from réserve
order by Date_Réserve, Heure_Réserve
```

Comment: It was taken from query written by "Su Sha", I didn't correct it. Question was about sorting so I answer him how to do this. `SELECT *` is another problem, not connected with this question.

Comment: So making sure your answer is the best it can be doesn't matter? You will notice that the subquery from the OP does contain a list of columns.

Comment: @psur, the inner query in the OP limits to the two columns so the `*` actually adds a potential for undesired columns, bad practice and a processing delay.

Comment: I've corrected it. Now we can begin discussion wheter using national characters in sql names is a good practice :)

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to use `ORDER BY` in your sub query - it is meaningless there.

For primary/secondary sort, you use a single `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT Date_Réserve,Heure_Réserve 
FROM réserve 
ORDER BY Date_Réserve, Heure_Réserve
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
SELECT Date_Réserve, Heure_Réserve FROMréserve ORDER BY Date_Réserve ASC, Heure_Réserve ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to order by more than one column:

```
select Date_Réserve,Heure_Réserve
from réserve
order by Date_Réserve, Heure_Réserve
```

If not, the order in subquery is useless.

Answer (score 1):

One clause, two parts

```
select 
            Date_Réserve,
            Heure_Réserve 
    from 
            réserve 
    order by 
             Date_Réserve, 
             Heure_Réserve
```

--

If this is just an example and you really need to order the results by a column that will be unavailable in the outer query you could do,

```
select 
            Date_Réserve,
            Heure_Réserve 
    from 
        (
            select 
                    (ROWNUMBER() OVER ORDER BY Date_Réserve) do,
                    Date_Réserve,
                    Heure_Réserve 
                from
                    réserve 
        )
    order by 
             do, 
             Heure_Réserve
```

but, as you can see, that would be pointless and inappropriate in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an order by in a sub query when you use a TOP statement.

```
select * from 
(select TOP 100 PERCENT Date_Réserve,Heure_Réserve from réserve order by Date_Réserve) t order by Heure_Réserve
```